# jquery access dynamic element IE7 IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I've an HTML element created dynamically with jQuery.

However I am not able to access the element via jQuery selectors in IE7/IE8.

ex:

```
var id = 45;
var $comment = $('#comment-'+id); // dynamically created element
alert($comment.length); // returns '0'
```

In other browsers is working ok.

Any advice?

Comment: Works in IE7/8: http://jsfiddle.net/s6frW/.

Comment: here's @pimvdb 's jsfiddle with dynamic element - also works in IE7/8 http://jsfiddle.net/s6frW/1/

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/7S6tj/).

Maybe another error happens in IE7/8 which prevents your code from running. For example, you might be using `JSON.parse()` method in your script, while IE7 doesn't have this object, or you may be using `getter`/`setter` functions, which are not supported in -IE9. I recommend that you see IE console, (F12), to see if everything is working fine or not.